# Mandar Datos de Tabla MYSQL-PHP a Otra Tabla con FORM - $_POST - foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla php que se llena de una base de datos mysql...

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>                                                     
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="24"><input type="submit" name="txtEnviar" value="Enviar" class="form-control"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ODC</th>
        <th class="text-center">Pedido</th>
        <th class="text-center">Modelo</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <? foreach ($arrPedido2 as $rowPedido2) { ?>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="txtNoOdc" value="<? echo $rowPedido2['noOdc'];?>"> <? echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['noOdc']);?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="txtPedido" value="<? echo $rowPedido2['pedido'];?>"><? echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['pedido']);?> </td>          
        <td class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="txtModelo" value="<? echo $rowPedido2['modelo'];?>"><? echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['modelo']);?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="txtIdPedido[]" value="<? echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['idPedido']);?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <? }; ?>
</tbody>
```

Y Quiero mandar los seleccionados mediante un checkbox a otra tabla

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>                                                     
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ODC</th>
        <th class="text-center">Pedido</th>
        <th class="text-center">Modelo</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td class="text-center"> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> </td>          
        <td class="text-center"> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Come seria?

Comment: ¿en la primer tabla no usas el boton submit? ¿el array $arrPedido2 trae valores previamente seleccionados de la base o esos valores cada uno cuenta con un checkbox que el usuario va seleccionando?

Comment: si en la primera tabla uso submit, y el array de $arrPedido2 vienen de una vase de datos y en el checkbox pongo de valor su id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo si es solo con PHP

Agrega un formulario a tu tabla, no olvides un boton para hacer el submit.

```
<form method="post" action="paimprimir.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="algo[]" value="algo">
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <button> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

En el otro archivo (por ejemplo el paimprimir.php), te van a llegar los seleccionados en el arreglo `$_POST['algo']`

sin embargo solo te llegarán los valores que le metiste al `value` del checkbox. (en mi ejemplo el string "algo").

---

### Si quisieras llevarte todos los datos de la tabla.

Bueno hay 2 métodos.

#### 1. El Más limpio y mejor para solo PHP.

En base a los ID enviados en el arreglo $_POST , hacer una nueva consulta que te traiga los datos de los seleccionados. `(esto es un ejemplo, ya tu sabrás tus tablas)`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN $_POST['algo']
```

Despues de eso ya haces lo mismo que hiciste en tu primera tabla y a imprimir.

#### 2. El fácil, pero complicado.

Ammm la verdad es que es meter todos los datos en un arreglo de Javascript y enviar ese arreglo a la nueva página, donde se procesará como tal.

La verdad el proceso es más tardado aunque más eficiente (en teoría) pues no tienes que hacer otra consulta a MySQL.

Sin embargo pues no daré más detalles al respecto, por que créeme si con PHP se te hizo complicado, entender la lógica del JS va a ser un problema.

Saludos

Comment: Hola amigo, intente tu método 1, me funciono pero solo me lleva un dato a la otra tabla, no me lleva mas de 2

Comment: Hola, el ejemplo que haces  `name="txtIdPedido[]" ` es el que hace la magia, tu mismo lo pusiste ¿como te llegan los `$_POST` a txtIdPedido[]?

Comment: prueba tu mismo como llegan con este método `var_dump($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

No puedes utilizar javaScript?
Es decir la solución debe ser dada solo con Php? y, las tablas estan en la misma pagina o paginas diferentes?

Comment: en paginas diferentes....solo que no se agrego el FORM en la primera tabla, de la primera se van a la segunda tabla que dicha tabla es un pdf que sirve para imprimir...

Comment: enviala por POST como un formulario y en la segunda tabla la llenas con el array que llega desde el post. Necesitas el codigo?

Comment: si pudieras ser amable si necesitara el ejemplo en código, ya yo lo implemento después, con respecto al mio.

Comment: Listo ahi esta en la otra respuesta... espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

> mira aqui esta, lo que se podria hacer es solo dejar un ID en el select y no enviar nada por hidden como lo tenias anteriormente, luego envias las IDs por POST y llega a la tabla 2 donde se hace la consulta a la BD con esas IDs y se llena la tabla. espero te sirva, cualquier inquietud, me la haces saber.
>   Saludos.

**TABLA 1**

```html
<?php
/************simulador de tabla de mysql***********************************/
 $arrPedido2 = array(
      array("noOdc" => "noOdc uno", "pedido" => "pedido uno", "modelo" => "modelo uno", "idPedido" => "1"),
      array("noOdc"=>"noOdc dos", "pedido"=>"pedido dos", "modelo"=>"modelo dos", "idPedido"=>"2"),
      array("noOdc"=>"noOdc dos", "pedido"=>"pedido dos", "modelo"=>"modelo dos", "idPedido"=>"3")
      );

 ?>
 <html>
 <body>
<table class="table table-striped" border=1>
<thead>                                                     
  
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ODC</th>
        <th class="text-center">Pedido</th>
        <th class="text-center">Modelo</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<form action='tabla2.php' method='POST'>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($arrPedido2 as $rowPedido2) { ?>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['noOdc']);?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['pedido']);?> </td>          
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['modelo']);?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="txtIdPedido[]" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($rowPedido2['idPedido']);?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }; ?>
   <tr>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="24"><input type="submit" name="txtEnviar" value="Enviar" class="form-control"></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**TABLA 2**

```html
<?php

$array_post = array();

foreach($_POST as $valor){
   array_push($array_post, $valor);
} 

echo 'Asi quedaria el arreglo de las filas seleccionadas: <br>';
print_r($array_post);
echo '<hr>';

/*Crear el IN para el sql */
$ids_Pedidos = '';

foreach ($array_post[0] as $rowPedido2){
 
 $ids_Pedidos = $ids_Pedidos."'".$rowPedido2."'," ;
}
 
 $ids_Pedidos = substr($ids_Pedidos, 0, -1); //uitar ultima coma

echo 'Debo hacer la consulta a la base de datos para sacar las ID que se seleccionaron anteriormente <br>';
echo  ' la consulta seria: <br><br>';

$CONSULTA = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE idPedido IN ('.$ids_Pedidos.');';

echo $CONSULTA;
 
/* LLENAR LA TABLA NORMAL CON EL RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA ANTERIOR*/

?>
```